# Jquery Function by id starting with

Tags: jquery, function, button, user-interface

Does Jquery or java have a "starts" function call?

Say I want a function to be called when any button containing an ID that starts with "clickEXP"

I noticed there is a starts with selector (http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

so I incorporated it in my function...

```
$('input[name^="clickExp"]').click(function () {}
```

but it doesn't seem to be firing when I click the button.

Comment: Your selector is referencing the `name` attribute instead of the `id` attribute.

Comment: Sorry, not paying attention to my context. Working great now. too bad I can't mark a comment as the answer . $('input[id^="clickExp"]').click(function () works great